# A problem involving sum of digits function and sum of square of digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I am trying to solve the following problem which appeared in the Mayo Olympiad in 2016.

Let $s(n)$ be the sum of digits of $n$ and let $s_2(n)$ be the sum of square of digits of $n$

**Problem.** *Give an example of a positive integer $n$ without the digit $0$ in its decimal expansion, such that $n\equiv 0\pmod{s_2(n)}$ and $s(n)=1001$.*

I was no able to solve it after many attempts. Any suggestion?

Comment: if $s(n)=1001$ then $n$ must have more than $100$ digits

Comment: @WW1 Yes, more that $1001/9>111$ digits. The number is also $\equiv 2\pmod{9}$.

Comment: So how could they possibly expect you to be able to express such an integer unless there is a lot of repetition, maybe it's something like the 1000 digit number that has 999 ones followed by a two, or perhaps the 143 digit number for which every digit is seven.

Comment: @WW1 Yes, exactly. Probably with many repetitions. This is a Math Olympiad problem. For example, the number with $n=11\ldots 1$ (1001 1's). One has $s(n)=1001$, $s_2(n)=1001$, but $n\equiv 100\pmod{s_2(n)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything starts with a guess.

Assume the desired number $A$ is a $502$-digit number including $499$ $2$'s and three $1$'s such that the first, third and $174$th digits (from right) are $1$;

$$A= 22 ... 2 1 2 .. 2121.$$

Then $s_2(A)=1999$ (which is a prime number) and $s(A)=1001$.

On the other hand:

$$A=2(\frac{10^{502}-1}{9})-10^{173}-10^2-1.$$

You can check that $A \equiv 0   (mod \ 1999)$ (I checked this with Wolfram).

Comment: but how did you guess that monster?

Comment: @DS First, I started with $500$ $2$'s and one $1$, and noted that such a number could be written as $2(\frac{10^{501}-1}{9})-10^m$. So we needed to have $2001|2(\frac{10^{501}-1}{9})-10^m$ which seemed impossible. Then, assuming having $499$ $2$'s and three $1$'s made me consider $1999|2(\frac{10^{502}-1}{9})-10^a-10^b-10^c$. Due to having three variables and $1999$ being a prime number, the last relation seemed to be solvable and it truly was even with fixing two of the three variable. So, I just managed to find $a=173$. I hope this explanation helps ...